# How to set minimum and maximum time in timepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I'm using [time picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to select only time in my app. The problem is that I need to set min and max time limits from the string. For example I have:

```
var min = '10:15:12';
var max = '19:15:12';
```

How to properly create date from it and append limits to already initialized time picker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    jQuery('#picker').timepicker({min: '8:00 am', max: '8:00 pm'})
```

or

```
   var picker=jQuery('#picker');
    var min = '10:15:12 am';
    var max = '07:15:12 pm';
    picker.timepicker('option','min',min);
    picker.timepicker('option','max',max);
```

you have another example:

```
  $('#picker').datetimepicker({
        minDate: new Date(2010, 11, 20, 8, 30),
        maxDate: new Date(2010, 11, 31, 19, 30)
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set these options:

### hourMin

Default: 0 - The minimum hour allowed for all dates.

### minuteMin

Default: 0 - The minimum minute allowed for all dates.

### secondMin

Default: 0 - The minimum second allowed for all dates.

### millisecMin

Default: 0 - The minimum millisecond allowed for all dates.

### microsecMin

Default: 0 - The minimum microsecond allowed for all dates.

### hourMax

Default: 23 - The maximum hour allowed for all dates.

### minuteMax

Default: 59 - The maximum minute allowed for all dates.

### secondMax

Default: 59 - The maximum second allowed for all dates.

### millisecMax

Default: 999 - The maximum millisecond allowed for all dates.

### microsecMax

Default: 999 - The maximum microsecond allowed for all dates.

Ref: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ --> Time Field Options